# Running seperate python scripts in same window

Tags: python

I have build a game in python, which uses OpenCV to fingerspell letters.
Through the first iteration of the program I have stumbled upon a problem regarding creating a GUI interface.

The problem is that I am using two python script one for recognition and one for displaying what the user currently fingerspelled.

I would like to make the two scripts run in a shared GUI like tKinter or PySimpleGui but without succeding.

I have used threading to run both python scripts to share data between them. As of now my solution is to click on the other window between letters which is not optimal.

Window for recognition:
[image: Seperate window for recognition]

Window for results:
[image]

So I would like the two windows to get merged into one is this possible in any way?

Comment: you can use threading for that https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: you can build tkinter GUI with two windows inside in a such way that two windows are run by two different threads (you can use `threading` for that)

Comment: Okay sounds interesting can you point me to any kind of example I have not been able to find anything regarding that thanks

Comment: Run PySimpleGUI in main thread and recognition in another thread. After recognized, call method `window.write_event_value` to generate an event and value to main thread to update GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this to be multithreaded?
Inside your game simply take a picture of the person on each draw loop and get the letter from that image.
If you need to display it you can always blit it to your pygame surface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).